# How to check if "Home screen shortcuts" permission was granted?

Tags: android, android-permissions, glance-appwidget

I want to add a Glance widget to the home screen directly from the app.

When I request to pin the widget, it prompts the user for permission. If the user denies it and then tries to pin the widget again, nothing will happen. I'd like to open the app settings so they can manually grant the necessary permission.

The problem is that I don't know the specific permission name, so I can't check if it was granted or not. I tried using `INSTALL_SHORTCUT`, but it's always in a Denied state even when the user has granted the required permission.

```
// request to pin the widget
GlanceAppWidgetManager(context).requestPinGlanceAppWidget(
    receiver =  TrackerWidgetReceiver::class.java
)
```

[image: Permission in settings]

[image: Permission asking]

Comment: Is this in the Emulator or on a device? If it is on device, can you update your question with the manufacturer and version of Android you are using?

Additionally, the system launcher should not be asking for a permission. However, third party launchers have a permission to allow them to pin widgets. This doesn't seem like the issue you are having however.

Comment: This is a device, Xiaomi 12 Pro. I attached the screenshot with the permission popup.

Comment: Have you received a response from the manufacturer yet?

Comment: I actually haven't asked the manufacturer about the problem